# How to add validation in phone number to display in the form of 123-456-7890 at checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Need to add validation in phone number and also display format i.e automatically it display in the form of 123-456-7890

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Create a custom validation rule. app/code/Mital/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Mital_Checkout/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. Add custom validation js file. app/code/Mital/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'moment'
], function ($, moment) {
    'use strict';

    return function (validator) {

        validator.addRule(
            'custom-validate-telephone',
            function (value, params) {                
                 var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})[-]\)?([0-9]{3}[-])?([0-9]{4})$/;

                if((value.match(phoneno))){
                    return true;
                }       
            },
            $.mage.__("Please enter phone number in form of 123-456-7890.")
        );

        return validator;
    };
});
```

> 3. app/code/Mital/Checkout/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">           
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="custom-phone-validation" type="Mital\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

> 4. Apply your custom rule for shipping and billing form app/code/Mital/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Mital\Checkout\Block\Checkout;
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
            /*For shipping address form*/

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['validation']['custom-validate-telephone'] = true;    
                   

            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) { 
                /* Telephone Billing Address */
                if (isset($payment['children']['form-fields']['children']['telephone'])) {
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['telephone']['validation'] = ['required-entry' => true, 'custom-validate-telephone' => true];
                }
            }
          
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you..!!
[You can download code from here](https://github.com/mitaldeveloper/magento2-checkout-validation)

Comment: thanks But I need to display in the form of 123-456-7890 in this form

Comment: Yes, it will display in the form of 123-456-7890.

Comment: It's not displaying it's display in the form of 1234567890

Comment: If we add something like that then it 12345678900000 then it display the validation message . But I need to display the phone number if we entered 123456789 then it displays 123-456-7890

Comment: Can you share a screenshot, please?

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/8089725?key=30d4f7ede30ce822d34149e9cbc86faa

Comment: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/8089740?key=6e8b9cde1f617b9c1c2c025da6d061e3

here I have added that no 1234567890

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124065/discussion-between-divya-and-mital-shah).

Comment: I edited my code and it's working. Please check here https://www.loom.com/share/695a36aa4a8246a0b593031ccc04ecbf

Answer (score 0):

Superb answer, Mital, I wish I could give a thumbs up--beautiful solution!
I would only add to help others utilizing this to remember that all references to your app/code/[vendor_name]/[module_name] have to be consistent in every file throughout the module (registration.php, requirejs-config.js, di.xml, etc.).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199274)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension, it automatically adds validation based on the selected country with the country flags and automatically sets the user country by default based on their Geo IP location.

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-telephonevalidation.html